# C#/Java Validate Unicode characters in Xamarin Android

Tags: java, c#

I’m sending XML to a 3rd party web service. Certain characters in the XML causes the web service to throw an exception, an example is:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable
>   to process request. ---> System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable
>   to translate Unicode character \u0193 at index 281 to specified code
>   page.

The exception is not thrown in certain circumstances:

1. If the character is within the first 0-255 characters of the Unicode character table, apart from some in the 128-160 range, or
2. For some specific Unicode characters above the 255 range, such as “ƒ” (402). I notice most of these are marked as “in WGL4” on this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). However, some which are marked as “in WGL4” do actually cause the exception.

We are seeing this issue when users type into a text box, or paste into the text box from a Word document or email (and the text is then sent to the web service).

I’d like to restrict which characters can be entered into the text box. As a start I have this rudimentary test:

```
if ((chr > 255) || (!XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(chr)))
{
  // Restrict character
}
```

However, that doesn’t permit some of the valid characters above 255. How can I add a condition to allow for these, without resorting to hardcoding a long list of possible values e.g. is there an existing method I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like server is encoding text to character set [`Windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), a very common code page for C# code on a Windows server.

To see if text only contains characters that can be encoded to `Windows-1252`, use this Java code:

```
String text = ...;
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("windows-1252").newEncoder();
if (! encoder.canEncode(text)) {
    // Text is not supported
}
```